# Union by single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have 2 tables in different databases and I want to be able to select all rows from `names_new` and the missing ones from `names` and would like to know where each one comes from.

```
+---------------+              +---------------+ 
|     NAMES     |              |   NAMES_NEW   |
+---------------+              +---------------+
| ID |   NAME   |              | ID |   NAME   |
+----+----------+              +----+----------+
|  1 |  Name1   |              |  1 |  Name1!  |
+----+----------+              +----+----------+
|  2 |  Name2   |              |  3 |  Name3   |
+----+----------+              +----+----------+

              +----------------------+ 
              |       RESULTS        |  <-- I want this result
              +----------------------+ 
              | ID |   NAME   | FROM | 
              +----+----------+------+
              |  1 |  Name1!  |  NEW |
              +----+----------+------+
              |  2 |  Name2   |  OLD |
              +----+----------+------+
              |  3 |  Name3   |  NEW |
              +----+----------+------+
```

Something like this, but that actually works

```sql
(
  SELECT
    n.ID as [ID],
    n.NAME as [NAME],
    'OLD' AS [FROM]
  FROM NAMES n
  UNION
  SELECT
    nn.ID as [ID],
    nn.NAME as [NAME],
    'NEW' as [FROM]
  FROM NAMES_NEW nn
)
ORDER BY NAME ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

I'm gonna show this in a webpage. So I will need to be able to add pagination and different where clauses.

*I have created a JDoodle here: https://jdoodle.com/a/U9k*

Comment: Don't call your column names things like `from`.  Or `select` or `join` or `where` or any other key word for that matter...

Comment: To add to @MatBailie's comment, these are all names/aliases that should be avoided [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in T-SQL. You *can* use keywords, like `Name` without quoting, however, I personally also suggest against it.

Comment: This was just a very basic sample of showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `union all` like this:

```
select nn.id, nn.name, 'new' as which
from names_new nn
union all
select n.id, n.name, 'old' as which
from names_old n
where not exists (select 1 from names_new nn where nn.id = n.id);
```

This compares the ids.  I'm not sure if you want to compare the ids or the names (or both) for prioritization purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any need for a `UNION` here, I think a `FULL OUTER JOIN` would likely provide a better solution:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NN.ID,N.ID) AS ID,
       ISNULL(NN.[NAME], N.[NAME]) AS [Name],
       CASE WHEN NN.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'NEW' ELSE 'OLD' END AS [From]
FROM dbo.NAMES N
     FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.NAMES_NEW NN ON N.ID = NN.ID;
```

Comment: I ended using Gordon Linoff's solution as it's easier to generate complex queries for his solution.

Comment: That doesn't mean it performs better though @Jeggy ; the other answer will require 3 table scans/lookups, rather than 2.